# GAS form- Onchange event in radio button, displaying an input box

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

One all day triying to display an input box if a radio button if checked on 'Si' value in a form made under google app script.  All logic i saw here for a normal JS-HTML form failed and can't realize what is wrong

```
<div class="w3-half">
    <label class="w3-text-brown"><b>¿Cuenta con alguna certificación o sello de calidad?</b></label>
   <div class="w1-one">
   <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="calidad" id="calidad" value="SI"onchange="my_function()" >
  <label>SI</label>
<input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="calidad"id="calidad" value="NO">
<label>NO</label>
 </div>
 </div>
        <div class="w3-half">
        <label class="w3-text-brown"><b>¿Cuál? </b></label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-sand" id="selloCali" type="text"style="display:none;">
        </div>
          
 </div>

        
        function my_function() {
        if( document.getElementById("calidad").value == 'Si' ){
   
        document.getElementById("selloCali").style.display = 'block';
        } else {
        document.getElementById("vigencia1").style.display = 'block';
 
        };
 
        };
```

Comment: Please note that i wrote sthe values 'SI' and after 'Si' but this wasn't the problem

Comment: There is not google apps script here.

Comment: Hi Cooper, i open an HTML into GAS and wrote the above code, the function between <script> . This is just the part of the HTML, i don't think is necesary to upload all the JS and Gs sheets

Comment: You question is unclear and it contains no google apps script.   Also the use of a foreign language makes it difficult to get context cues and is less likely to be answered. You mentioned a form but you don't have any form tags.  It's poor formatted.  There are not script tags.  It a waste of our time.